# Prestashop 1.5 Webservice Updating Customer id_default_group PHP

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I need to automatically update the prestashop->customers->customer->id_default_group value using PHP via the Prestashop webservice. The script knows the new value and it is done before/as the page loads.

I can get a customer record, or I can get just the "id_default_group" of a customer record but I run into trouble when I try changing the record value and updating the webservice. I get back "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request".

It seems like I am incorrectly trying to update the xml or object.

It would be preferable to do all this by only getting and updating the "id_default_group" and not having to retrieve the complete customer record.

I have:

```
define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://www.site.com/');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'yuyiu');
require_once('../PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

// First : We always get the customer's list or a specific one
try
{
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
    $opt = array('resource' => 'customers');  // Full customer record
    //$opt = array('resource'=>'customers','display'=> '[id_default_group]','filter[id]' => '['.$_SESSION["iemIdCustomer"].']'); // Customer id_default_group value
    if (isset($_SESSION['iemIdCustomer'])){
        $opt['id'] = $_SESSION['iemIdCustomer'];
    }

    $xml = $webService->get($opt);

    // The elements from children
    $resources = $xml->children()->children();
    // $resources = $xml->children()->children()->children(); // If just getting id_default_group
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)
{
    // Here we are dealing with errors
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
    else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
    else echo 'Other error';
}

// Second : We update the data and send it to the web service
if (isset($_SESSION['iemIdCustomer'])){

    // Update XML with new values
    $xml->customers->customer->id_default_group = 4;
    //$resources = $xml->children()->children()->children();

    // And call the web service
    try
    {
        $opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
        //$opt = array('resource'=>'customers','display'=> '[id_default_group]','filter[id]' => '['.$_SESSION["iemIdCustomer"].']');
        $opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
        $opt['id'] = $_SESSION['iemIdCustomer'];
        //$opt['display'] = 'id_default_group';
        $xml = $webService->edit($opt);
        // if WebService succeeds
        echo "Successfully updated.";
    }
    catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
    {
        // Dealing with errors
        $trace = $ex->getTrace();
        if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
        else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
        else echo 'Other error<br />'.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This is basic for those in the know so I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance,
Lance

Answer (score 1):

Ok I go the following to work.

The following line seem to do the trick:

```
$xml->children()->children()->id_default_group = 4;
```

Follows is the line with the rest of the code to do the task.

```
    // Get the customer's id_default_group
try
{
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);

    $opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
    $opt['id'] = $_SESSION["iemIdCustomer"];
    $xml = $webService->get($opt);

    // Get the elements from children of customer
    $resources = $xml->children()->children()->children();
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)
{
    // Here we are dealing with errors
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
    else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
    else echo 'Other error';
}

// Update the data and send it to the web service

    // Update XML with new value
    $xml->children()->children()->id_default_group = 4;

    // And call the web service
    try
    {
        $opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
        //$opt = array('resource'=>'customers','display'=> '[id_default_group]','filter[id]' => '['.$_SESSION["iemIdCustomer"].']');
        $opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
        $opt['id'] = $_SESSION['iemIdCustomer'];
        //$opt['display'] = 'id_default_group';
        $xml = $webService->edit($opt);
        // if WebService don't throw an exception the action worked well and we don't show the following message
        echo "Successfully updated.";
    }
    catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
    {
        // Here we are dealing with errors
        $trace = $ex->getTrace();
        if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
        else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
        else echo 'Other error<br />'.$ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Hope that it assists someone.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have this error because you are editing the bad node ;)
try with

```
$xml->customer->id_default_group = 4;
```

That should be OK :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I fixed the issue before I saw it as missed the notification email. Fixed it with $xml->children()->children()->id_default_group = 4;